# ASP.NET Session StateServer - is it possible to extract info about current sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm looking into changing the ASP.NET session state mode of our application from SQLServer to StateServer (for performance reasons).

In SQLServer mode, it is easy to extract information about the current sessions by querying SQL Server tables like ASPStateTempSessions. e.g. things like when each session was created, when it is due to expire, etc. You could even query the session state blob data to extract further application specific info (e.g. like the UserID, if it was saved in session state). This info was useful for administrators.

Just wondering if anyone has managed to do something similar for StateServer mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx) for the state server that might be useful, but they don't give you information for individual sessions.